# signed apk not getting installed form gmail attachment

Tags: android, apk

I have built a test android app and signed it successfully and then sent it to someone to test via email. They click on the attachment in the email it is showing no action just name of the file is visible no install or download option is coming.I am using gmail for sending and receiving as well.But when i am copying the apk file from the bin folder and sending it it is working fine,so please help me out why signed apk is not working

Comment: you can't install the same app with different keys ... so if on device is already installed app from "bin" you can install "exported" one ...

Comment: intalling is next step the attachment of signed apk is not showing any option in email just the name is visible

Answer (score 1):

when I open email containing APK from Native email app, I also face similar problem. Try to open email from Browser, and you will get download option. After downloading, you can install. Hope this will work!

Comment: tha apk from bin folder is showing fine in naitive gmail app what is the problem with sigend app